# Android Resource Folders (drawables)

Tags: android, performance, android-drawable, android-screen-support

I am not sure if this has been asked earlier, as I couldn't search the issue (may be I am not aware of the exact terms).

I am trying to understand how resource folders work in Android as there are so many to support screen sizes, density pixels etc.

I read [this](http://pivotallabs.com/understanding-android-resource-folders/) and understood few things.

Now what I want to know is, does creating many folders (drawables for mdpi, hdpi etcx for example) with the same images acquires or increases the application size?

Any help or direction would be great? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can use a nine patch drawable. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch.

Comment: thanks @Raghunandan this can be a work around. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Now what I want to know is, does creating many folders (drawables for
>   mdpi, hdpi etcx for example) with the same images acquires or
>   increases the application size?

Yes, it does, all of them are included in the apk, since there is only one apk for all devices and resolutions.

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) android selects the current resources at runtime based on your device, and more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) about best ways to support multiple screen sizes in your application.

Comment: Thanks. :) +1 for the simple and straight answer. But then is there a way to dodge this as at one end we want to support more and more devices and on the other we have Out Of Memory in our face?

Comment: Using correctly the resources should ensure you to don't have Out of Memory because of the resources, commonly this kind of erros are related with bad management of bitmaps (not recycling them). Anyway a good solution is to use a 9patch drawable as Raghunandan suggests

Answer (score 0):

As you have read the basics already, you know how android has various resource folders.

For each screen density we can have a different drawable folder.

`Does creating many folders with the same images acquires or increases the application size?`

Yes, as the number of files will be increased, the size of app will increase.

You can use tools such as [`Resizer`](https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/downloads/detail?name=Resizer_1.3.1.exe&can=2&q=) to input an image of one resolution and create multiple images and folders as specified initially.

Comment: Thanks mate, but my query is a bit on the other side. ;-)